# How to install visual debugger for JupyterLab?

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am working on Windows 10. I am trying to install the visual debugger on my Jupyter Notebook. I followed the protocols described at https://blog.jupyter.org/a-visual-debugger-for-jupyter-914e61716559. The following is the install commands:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/debugger
conda install xeus-python -c conda-forge
```

When I tried to open xpython to activate debugger, I am getting the following error displayed on a popup box.

> xpython.exe - System Error
>
> The code execution cannot proceed because libzmq-mt-4_3_1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The only way to remove the popup box is to reboot the system. Is there any solution to properly installing the debugger? The Jupyter Lab says the latest version comes with the prebuilt debugger. Even there I have the same dll missing error message.

Comment: Linking an older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655445/jupyter-lab-xpython-debug-error-missing-dll-libzmq

Comment: Could you please try to create a new clean conda environment and install JupyterLab 3.0 and xeus-python there from conda-forge only, ideally disabling the default channel (i.e. other than conda-forge)? One of the authors responded [here](https://medium.com/@SylvainCorlay/i-recommend-not-mixing-the-default-channel-with-the-conda-forge-channel-10b0ebc6173b) that it might be because of conflicting binaries being pulled from different channels. Please let us know if it helped!